# How to read command line argument in shell sript

Tags: shell

I need to read command line argument which is passing as
 scriptname –c "30,31,32,33,34,35"

and convert it to

myArray=( 30 31 32 )

Comment: What happened to 33, 34, and 35 in that example? :-)

Comment: in the argument any number between 31,32,33,34,35 can be passed as –c "30,31,32,33,34,35"

Comment: And why are 33, 34, and 35 in the example given at command line but omitted in the array? That's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
while getopts c: option
do
    case $option in
       c) data="$OPTARG"
          ;;
    esac
done

oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=','
myArray=($data)
IFS="$oldIFS"

echo ${myArray[@]}
```

The `c:` after `getopts`indicates that we have an option `-c`, the `:` indicates it is followed by an argument, which is retrieved using `$OPTARG`.

`IFS` if the Inter Field Separator which I reset to a comma in order to create the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use getopts command to read the arguments.
Please refer the link for the usage
[example of how to use getopts in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash)

Once you have the variables, you can easily create an array 
This link might be useful.
[Arrays in unix shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878882/arrays-in-unix-shell)