# Bash AWK, get first and second output (int)

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a script where I write the score to a file, named log.txt

In this file I save the score like this: (number 1 is just a example)

```
Won: 1
Lose: 1
```

I've written this AWK command:

```
gameswon=`awk -F : '{print $2}' "$file"`
```

It gives me this result:

```
1 1
```

How can I save the first number to, "won"
And the second number to "lose"

Hope anyone can help me

Comment: Was it really necessary to use an image for that simple output? Can't you just paste a line of text?

Comment: You're right @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878882/arrays-in-unix-shell):

```
gameswon=($(awk -F: '{print $2}' "$file"))
won=${gameswon[0]}
lose=${gameswon[1]}
```

This puts the output of `awk -F: '{print $2}' "$file"` into the array `$gameswon`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read` with little modifier awk in process substitution:

```
read -r won lose < <(awk -F : '$1 ~ /^(Won|Lose)$/{printf "%s ", $2+0}' "$file")
```