# how to extract values into separate variables from a stream of space separated data

Tags: bash, unix, getopts

I need to separate the input into different values after reading it from command line. I am reading it using the **`OPTARGS`** method along with `while` loop.
So my input will be like "hostanme1 hostname2 hostnamen"

How can I loop in through this to extract the hostnames in separate variables.

```
    while getopts S:H: opt
do
   case ${opt} in
      S)
        SCHNAME=${OPTARG}
      ;;
      H)
        HOST=${OPTARG}
      ;;
      *)
        DisplayUsage
        exit 1
      ;;
   esac
done
```

This will be run like `./filename.ksh  -S schema -H "Host1 host2 host3 host4`

Comment: Show your code with sample input and expected output.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with oracle? If not please remove the tag.

Comment: @KaushikNayak my bad removed

Comment: Instead of `HOST=${OPTARG}` use `hosts=(${OPTARG})` then you will have an array `hosts` that has hostname in various elements.

Comment: @anubhava didnt work. It just took the first value which is host1 and not the rest of them

Comment: @PreetiMaurya you step through the array with: `for this in "${HOST[@]}"; do`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to add '(' and ')' around a string with spaces between items to make an array of objects.

```
  H)
    HOSTS=(${OPTARG})
  ;;

for host in "${HOSTS[@]}"
do
  echo "$host"
done
```

Comment: It just took the first value from the options provided. I want all of them.. I will give the hosts in double quotes while executing

Comment: That should be `for host in "${HOSTS[@]}"; do`

Comment: You should use quotes, per my previous comment. Otherwise, an array element containing a space will be treated as two elements. Probably not an issue with a list of hostnames, but it's still way better to keep a standard style to your code and maintain good habits.

Comment: @GoinOff curious to know how the for loop works. Seeing this for the first time. Newbie

Comment: @Preeti here is a good post on the subject https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878882/arrays-in-unix-shell

Comment: individual items in a bash array can be accessed in the following way: `${HOSTS[0]}` for first element, `${HOSTS[1]}` for seconds element

Comment: thats a great article. Thank you @GoinOff