# Make an array declaration work for all linux shells

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I have a function defined in my script:

```
export_path()
{
  array=($(echo $PATH | awk -F":" '{print $0}'))
  if ! [ $(echo ${array[*]} | grep "/usr/bin" > /dev/null 2>&1) ]; then export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin;fi
  if ! [ $(echo ${array[*]} | grep "/usr/sbin" > /dev/null 2>&1) ]; then export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin;fi
  if ! [ $(echo ${array[*]} | grep "/bin" > /dev/null 2>&1) ]; then export PATH=$PATH:/bin;fi
  if ! [ $(echo ${array[*]} | grep "/sbin" > /dev/null 2>&1) ]; then export PATH=$PATH:/sbin;fi
 }
```

`array=($(echo $PATH | awk -F":" '{print $0}'))` works well for `bash` but not for `sh`.

I need to find a way to make the array definition work across all shells.

Comment: Have a look at the 3rd answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878882/arrays-in-unix-shell)

Comment: @Aserre Thanks for the reference. Got my answer

Comment: /bin/sh on recent versions of Debian (and Ubuntu) doesn't support arrays at all. But see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/39751/add-directory-to-path-if-its-not-already-there) for other ways to accomplish the same thing.